# How to deploy multiple uDeploy components using jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, urbancode, udeploy

Eg.

uDeploy documentation available related to Jenkins udeploy integration. 
We can specify only one component Name, one application name and one process name in udeploy plugin in jenkins. 
But I got multiple components attached to application in uDeploy, and I would like to configure these multiple udeploy components in Jenkins CI job. Please help me how to use multiple components in using jenkins job to invoke uDeploy.

Comment: did the answer help you?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options recommended in the official [documentation](https://developer.ibm.com/urbancode/docs/integrating-jenkins-ibm-urbancode-deploy/),

If you want to push artifacts from a single build into multiple components, you have some other options.

Use the command line client as part of your build to push new versions.
Deliver each component to an alternate repository that UCD is monitoring such as a file system drop area, Maven repo or Rational Asset Manager.

Here are the documentations to the individual CLI command lines.

Step 1: [Upload component version to code station](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.1.0/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_addversionfiles.html)

Step 2: [Execute Application Process](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4GSP_6.1.0/com.ibm.udeploy.api.doc/topics/udclient_requestapplicationprocess.html)

These should get you started!